# Normal sheaf of non-reduced locally complete intersection space curves

Tags: deformation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes, moduli-spaces

Let $C$ be a non-reduced locally complete intersection curve on a smooth degree $d$ surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (for example a non-reduced Cartier divisor). For simplicity we can assume that $d>deg(C)$. Denote by $C_r$ the reduced scheme associated to $C$. It is clear the normal sheaves, $N_{C|\mathbb{P}^3}$ and $N_{C_r|\mathbb{P}^3}$ are locally free. Also, recall under the closed immersion, $i:C_r \hookrightarrow C$ we have the canonical maps, $i^*:H^0(N_{C|\mathbb{P}^3}) \to H^0(i^*N_{C|\mathbb{P}^3})$ and $H^0(N_{C_r|\mathbb{P}^3}) \to H^0(i^*N_{C|\mathbb{P}^3})$.

The question is whether it is true that the image of the latter map is contained in the image of $i^*$.

Comment: What is the second map?

Comment: I don't understand why $N_{C/{\bf P}^3}$ is locally free in general, unless you always assume that $C$ is a Cartier divisor.

Comment: @Rossler: Sorry, I meant to write a local complete intersection curve. Will update the question.


Comment: @Sasha: The second map arises from the natural morphism: $N_{C_r|\mathbb{P}^3} \to i^*N_{C|\mathbb{P}^3}$

Comment: That is my question. How do you construct such a morphism? 

Comment: @Sasha: As far as I understand it arises from $i^∗(I_C/I_C^2) \to I_{C_r}/I_{C_r}^2$ and then taking the $Hom_{C_r}(−,\mathcal{O}_{C_r})$. This is a standard map while defining the tangent space to a flag Hilbert scheme. 